# Tesla Coil based on Slayer Exciter Circuit Issue

Tags: transformer, mosfet-driver, tesla-coil

I'm making my first Tesla coil, which is based on a slayer exciter circuit. It's a slayer exciter circuit that uses a npn bjt (TIP31C) to drive the Mosfet(IRFP460) gate.  I tried to simulate my circuit in LTSPICE and I believe something is wrong (I think that the output voltage should be around 2kV according to my estimates). I'm not sure if it's because I didn't build it properly or if I overlooked something.

[image: Slayer Exciter]

[image: Result]